# ACF Wordpress styling custom fields

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, advanced-custom-fields

I have an issue with styling each field of ACF in .php file.

```
<?php  the_field('service_section_title'); ?>
<?php  the_field('service_section_description'); ?>
    <a href="<?php  the_field('service_section_button_link'); ?>">Learn more</a>

    <?php if( have_rows('services') ):

while ( have_rows('services') ) : the_row();

   $image = get_field('service_icon');  if( !empty($image) ):

<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />


    get_field('service_title');
    get_field('service_description');

endwhile; else : endif; ?>
```

How exactly I should put HTML to wrap my

get_field('service_title');

get_field('service_description');

And Image field;

For example:

```
                    <p class="text-faded">?php get_field('service_description');?>
                    </p>
```

How to wrap php with html in a correct way (not breaking the php code with php and then interrupting again)

Comment: After `$image = get_field('service_icon');  if( !empty($image) ):` just add `?>` to close it, then after the `img` tag add `<?php` to start it again.

Comment: Ok. I thought there is other "prettier" way.

Comment: You could also just echo the image: `echo '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" />`. Just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest you do:

```
<?php if (have_rows('repeater')): ?>
    <?php while (have_rows('repeater')): the_row(); ?>

    <?php
    $variable = get_sub_field('variable');
    ?>

    <div class="repeater-item">
        <div class="variable-item">
            <?php echo $variable; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

All you do after this is style everything inside div class="variable-item" and then you can style anything in there.